# Websocket connections cannot be made with NginX/FastCGI

Tags: nginx, websocket, go

I have a web application written in Go.  When I run the application with the web server that comes with the standard library, websocket connections work fine.

However, when I run the web application as a FastCGI application and use NginX as a proxy, the websocket connection cannot be established.  I get this error message:

```
websocket: response does not implement http.Hijacker
```

I am using [Gorilla Toolkit's websocket library](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) for websocket connections and have the following setup:

Go Handler:

```
func NotificationsWebSocket(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ws, err := websocket.Upgrade(w, r, nil, 1024, 1024)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }
    //...
}

//...

router.HandleFunc("/notifications", NotificationsWebsocket)

//...

tcp, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9000")
handleErr(err)
err = fcgi.Serve(tcp, router)
```

nginx.conf

```
location ~ ^.+$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

One way I could go about this is have a FastCGI connection for all the regular web handlers and run a separate web server just for the websocket handler, and then handle the /notifications path in NginX accordingly, but I want to avoid that if at all possible.

Does anyone know if there's a way to configure NginX to allow the connection to be upgraded to websockets?

Comment: What version of nginx are you using? Support for websockets was only added in 1.3.13, so if you're using an older version you'll need to upgrade.

Comment: I'm using 1.4.5.  I know I could add another location directive for /notifications in nginx.conf and split the WebSocket handler into another web server, but I was wondering if there's a way to just do it in FastCGI.

Comment: the error you are getting is that the fcgi response is not also a Hijacker (websockets use the hijacker interface to take over the tcp socket).  It doesn't have anything to do with nginx versions.  FCGI is not compatible with websockets, you need to have another server and reverse proxy to it

Comment: Okay, that clears everything up.  Can you post that as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error you are getting is that the fcgi response is not also a Hijacker (websockets use the hijacker interface to take over the tcp socket).

It doesn't have anything to do with nginx versions.

Also, FCGI is not compatible with websockets, you need to have another server and reverse proxy to it